# Scrape dags folder to extract ExternalTaskSensor tasks and parameters

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

We've made extensive use of [ExternalTaskSensor][1] to the point where the quantity of cross-dag dependencies have become difficult to track. As such we would like a method of extracting all tasks that use this sensor as well as the parameters passed to these tasks such as `external_dag_id` and `external_task_id`. Extracting this info would allow us to create a list of dependencies (and maybe a graph if we want it).

Approach:
So far we've been able to use the `list_dags` cli option to get a list of all dags. For each dag we then run the `list_tasks` option with the `-t` parameter to get a list of tasks and the operator used. The next step is to retrieve the parameters passed to these tasks, this is where we are stuck. Are there any official or non-official methods of scraping this data?

Info:
We are running Airflow 1.10.9 and Composer 1.11.0. Our script so far is written in python3.
[1]: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
dag_models = session.query(DagModel).filter(DagModel.is_active.is_(True)).all()

for dag_model in dag_models:
     dag = dag_model.get_dag()
     for task in dag.task_dict.values():
         if isinstance(task, ExternalTaskSensor):
             do_smth(task.external_dag_id, task.external_task_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit [Airflow's metadb](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html) for this.

- either query directly

  ````
  SELECT operator
  FROM task_instance
  WHERE dag_id = 'my_dag'
    AND task_id = 'my_task';```
  ````
- or use `SQLAlchemy`

  ```
  from airflow.utils.session import provide_session
  from airflow.models import TaskInstance

  @provide_session
  def get_operator_name(my_dag_id: str, my_task_id: str, session=None) -> str:
      """Fetch TaskInstance from the database using pickling"""
      task_instance: TaskInstance = session.query(TaskInstance).filter(TaskInstance.dag_id == my_dag_id).filter(TaskInstance.task_id == my_task_id).first()
      return task_instance.operator
  ```

The downside of this approach is that it wouldn't work until `task` has run at least once (and it's entry has been created in `TaskInstance` table)

---

Reference

- [`cli.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/cli.py#L179)

Comment: The `task_instance` metadata table does not contain data about the external_dag_id and external_task_id passed to the ExternalTaskSensor.